# Mean independence and normality imply independence?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, independence, means

Let $\varepsilon, X$ be real-valued random variables. Could you help me to show (if correct) that

(1) $E(\varepsilon)=E(\varepsilon\mid X)$

and

(2) $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$

imply that $\varepsilon\perp X$?

If the statement is wrong what would be the "corrected" version?

Comment: Did you try to find some counterexamples? There are some rather simple ones...

Comment: I can't think about any. Could you give some help?

Comment: "I can't think about any" Hmmm... No idea of a situation where E(Y|X)=0 but (X,Y) is not independent?

Comment: OK, now I understand, thanks. Is there any special rule when we have a normality assumption?

Comment: Good. So, the example you have in mind would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X=\epsilon^2$, and $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$.